# How can you create an NSTimer in a Sprite kit game with Swift?

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode8, swift4

In a **Single view controller application**, you can use:

```
Foundation.Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.updateFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But, when you use that code in a **Spritekit game**, it comes up with errors and doesn't work.

What can I use that **works**?

Comment: What errors do you get? I use a timer as well in my Spritekit game and it works just fine.

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: The main error seems to be with the #selector for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start your timer like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene{

    var timer: Timer!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
         timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.yourFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func yourFunction(){
        print("timer function")
    }

    func goToAnotherScene(){
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Note that you need to set @objc before your function

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem!

Comment: FYI if you leave your app, this code will break/get you incorrect results

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend staying away from NSTimer/Timer.  SpriteKit has it's own timing functions, and getting NSTimer/Timer to work bug free is a huge hassle and undertaking.  Use `SKAction's` for 99% of your timing needs.  If you provided the code, I would be better able to assist with a proper answer.